# Checksum Error on restoring userdata*****.backup file

Tags: backup, restore

I gave my [Phone](http://www.gsmarena.com/celkon_a95-4822.php) (Celkon A95) into a service centre because of touch malfunctioning before it I backed up the user data by pressing Power and Vol+ buttons, it gave me a backup file called userdata20130902_131223.backup. After a few days I got my phone back and when I restored the data it gave me "Checksum Error". I'm unable to restore my previous data. Is there any way get back at least messages and contacts?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Had you synced your contacts with a Google account? If so they should all be backed up automatically.

Comment: so, what about messages..?? can i extract that backup file in pc..??

Comment: Maybe try extracting it using this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/ FYI I don't know how to import them back into Android and I've never tried the program so make a back up of the backup just in case it does something silly.

Answer (score 1):

It's a 512 byte header in front of a "tar.gz"

```
hexdump -C userdata_xxxxxxxx_yyyyyy.backup | less
```

showed the magical zip header "1f8b0800 00000000" at offset 0x200
So, skipping 512 bytes, the rest can be gunzip | tar

```
dd if=userdata_xxxxxxxx_yyyyyy.backup bs=512 skip=1 | gunzip -c | tar xv
```

In the `/data/` directory, hunt down the db file.  It's a sqlite3 database file which you can view with a variety of tools, e.g. `sqlitebrowser`

Answer (score 1):

Stock Android recovery backup files can be restored with a Nandroid custom recovery, if you simply repack them into tar archive.

i put this two command lines in a dirty shell script (extract + repack as tar). thanks to ektoric figuring out his gunzip method!

the shell script will convert your backup file into nandroid backup automatically. download >bckp2cwm.zip< at

From http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=65374561#post65374561