# How to extract .backup files created by android stock recovery?

Tags: backup, recovery-mode, data-recovery

I'm using Coolpad note 3 lite, running Android 5.1. I created internal memory backup using stock recovery. Files were created in this format:

1. userdata_yyyymmdd_HHMMSS.backup  = 2GB
2. userdata_yyyymmdd_HHMMSS.backup1 = 2GB
   n. ...
3. userdata_yyyymmdd_HHMMSS.backup5 = 1.53GB

Is there any way to extract the files to PC? I couldn't see file header mentioned [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=64215705&postcount=13). Another user referred [a method](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=65379406&postcount=21), which I couldn't understand.

- Android 5.1
- TWRP installed
- Rooted
- FAT32 internal & SD card.
- Tried Titanium backup and it don't recognize the format.

**Edit**:

1. Tried to do a stock recovery backup and replace the files. While trying to restore stock recovery not showing SD card, although it takes backup in SD card during backup in same session.
2. 7Zip Windows opened the merged .backup file. It shows "2.ext".
   [image]
3. Mounting 2.ext in Ubuntu shows nothing even though file space is occupied.
   [image]
4. When trying to open 2.ext using 7zip, I see lot of files in similar name and opening them in 7zip again shows again same file names....
   [image]

Now how do I recovery files from this 2.ext?

Comment: @ManishRamavat No solution yet, I just run foremost in Ubuntu to recover my photos. That's not recovering great either.

Comment: this is solution for your ext4 image https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=73612779&postcount=58

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, you will need to merge the various .backup*N* files into one by using the following command:

`cat userdata_yyyymmdd_HHMMSS.backup* > userdata_yyyymmdd_HHMMSS.backup`

It looks like the header size of 512 bytes is the same across many devices, so try to extract using the following command:

`dd if=userdata_xxxxxxxx_yyyyyy.backup bs=512 skip=1 | gunzip -c | tar xv`

If this doesn't work, you can try the other method as described in [this post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=65374561#post65374561):

1. Download the **simg2img** tool from [here](http://web.djodjo.org/article/download/android/tools/x86_linux/ext4tools).
2. Convert the .backup file into an image using command `simg2img userdata_xxxxxxxx_yyyyyy.backup userdata_xxxxxxxx_yyyyyy.backup.raw`
3. Mount the image using command `mount -t ext4 -o loop,rw userdata_xxxxxxxx_yyyyyy.backup.raw "data"`.

You should now be able to copy the contents of the backup image.

Alternatively, you can [download](http://www.mediafire.com/download/n84s548dx56ahyn/bckp2cwm.zip) the simg2img binary along with the script that automates the above steps using the link from the above mentioned [post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=65374561#post65374561).

Comment: Tried with Cygwin, unable to cat files (no space issue). Downloading ubuntu for VM and update the status.

Comment: First method didn't work because of 
"gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: This does not look like a tar archive". simg2img can't open the merged file. "Cannot open input file userdata.backup". Any other ideas? How to do with fallocate as another user mentioned?

Comment: @Jones Are you able to use `md5sum`? If yes, then try to issue `md5sum -ve '1/1 "%02X "' userdata_yyyymmdd_HHMMSS.backup | head -n 10`, then tell us the output. This way, we could try to identify the file type for you.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman - "md5sum: invalid option -- 'v'" I'm getting this error. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jones No, it just means that your build of `md5sum` does not support the `-v` flag. You may want to skip the `-e` flag as well, and use `md5sum -C` instead. This will output both the hexadecimal code and its ASCII transliteration.

Comment: As an alternative to this manual procedure, you may also want to check if your Ubuntu distro has the `file` or the `magic` command, which are able to identify files by examining their header.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman - Used file with c flag. No patterns found.

Comment: @Jones Then we should perform an hexadecimal dump in order to manually analyze the file.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman - Now I'm able to see the internals of backup, although I couldn't retrieve anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

https://android.stackexchange.com/a/137339

> stock android recovery extracted files can be restored with nandroid custom recovery, if you simply repack them into tar archive.
>
> i put this two command lines in a dirty shell script (extract + repack as tar).
> thanks to ektoric figuring out his gunzip method!
>
> download on
> http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=65374561#post65374561