# andriod wifi dhcp problem: trying to solve via restoring a modified backup

Tags: wi-fi, backup, restore, dhcp

It's not the first time this problem is listed. Suddenly connecting to any wireless networks fails by getting stuck on obtaining IP address. This happened after I enabled airplane mode for the first time. I enabled wifi while in airplane mode (shouldn't be possible right?), realised I was still in airplane mode and disabled it. This broke the wifi, I'd guess the DHCP.

A workaround is using a static IP, this still works. A solution is a factory reset, this solves the problem. I backed up before this, restoring the backup also restores the problem. I'd like to find an actual fix and not install and configure everything again.

So I made a backup of a fresh factory reset system and I have the backup of my own system. By using this:

```
dd if=userdata_xxxxxxxx_yyyyyy.backup bs=512 skip=1 | gunzip -c | tar xv
```

from here
[How to extract .backup files created by android stock recovery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141805/how-to-extract-backup-files-created-by-android-stock-recovery)
I can read the content of the backup of my broken system.

So to solve the issue I need this:

1. to find the files responsible for the wifi mess and replace them
2. reverse the extraction process

I can make resonable guesses about both but help is needed. For the first I would guess this:

```
 find . | grep dhcp
./misc/dhcp
./misc/dhcp/dhcpcd-wlan0.pid
./misc/dhcp/dhcpcd-wlan0.lease
./misc/dhcp/dhcp6c_duid
```

As per here:
https://thealarmclocksixam.com/2013/10/26/dhcp-failure-on-android-wifi-stuck-on-obtaining-ip-address-how-i-solved-it/

And maybe these

```
find . | grep wifi                               
./data/com.asus.wifidirect
./data/com.asus.wifidirect/cache
./data/com.asus.wifidirect/cache/com.android.renderscript.cache
./data/com.asus.wifidirect/shared_prefs
./data/com.asus.wifidirect/shared_prefs/wifidirect_SharedPreferences.xml
./data/com.asus.wifidirect/lib
./misc/wifi
./misc/wifi/sockets
./misc/wifi/softap.conf
./misc/wifi/p2p_supplicant.conf
./misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
./misc/wifi/entropy.bin
./misc/wifi/ipconfig.txt
```

Simply replacing those directories would be worth a try

The second problem: first creating a tar, applying gunzip in the correct way and then using dd or cat to add the first 512 bytes header. I'm no hero with shell commands, I nearly always understand what I'm doing but coming up with them is different.
I'd guess something like

```
tar -czvf userdata.tar.gz *
```

Should do the complete trick for the packing.

```
dd if=userdata_20161009_165440.backup bs=512 count=1 of=userdata_header
```

Should give me a header out of the original file

```
cat userdata_header userdata.tar.gz > userdata.backup
```

Should finish the process

If this works it may be a solution to a common problem that doesn't require rooting the device or living with a static ip workaround. All went well so far but when I tried to restore my home made backup file I get:

```
error: checksum compare failed
```

Which makes be suspect the header is actually a checksum, but I have no experience with those. Can anyone give me suggestions? If I can determine how the header is a valid checksum I can then try to make my own for my custom backup

Comment: You can try to simply delete the .pid and .lease files in /data/misc/dhcp as described in the linked side you mentioned (https://thealarmclocksixam.com/2013/10/26/dhcp-failure-on-android-wifi-stuck-on-obtaining-ip-address-how-i-solved-it/).

Comment: Enabling WiFi while in airplane mode is a feature and correct behavior. WiFi has much less range than a normal cellular connection and some planes even offer WiFi in the business class. Cellular connection is only*banned* because of the high range and interference (and the fact that the next cell tower has to direct its power to you when you are near enough).

Comment: That requires rooting the tablet, something I don't want to do