# Remove lock or enable usb debugging on non-rooted phone?

Tags: adb, usb, data-recovery, locked-out

So my little sister locked herself out of her phone which was not rooted, had no recovery software (Cwm, Xrec, etc.) installed on it, and has usb debugging and auto-mount disabled. We don't know the google account associated with the phone. Basically all I have is the phone and a usb cable. Is there a way to get the user data out of it? Adb won't recognise the device btw. I do apologise if it's a stupid question. The phone automatically connected to the wifi, and I'm on Linux, if that helps.

Update: managed to get into recovery but adb only recognises the device in sideload mode.

Comment: check if this thread helps https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2487147

Comment: Thanks, I found a work around, I'm not sure this works on all android versions. I inserted a micro sd, went into recovery, backed up user data onto the card, put the card into my computer, extracted the .backup file as explained here <http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141805/how-to-extract-backup-files-created-by-android-stock-recovery>, went into the accounts.db file, found the google account, recovered it with the associated phone number and unlocked the phone.

Comment: What phone and version of Android?  Potentially see http://android.stackexchange.com/q/127739/1465