# How to restore backup taken using stock recovery?

Tags: backup, restore

I have an unrooted Coolpad Note 3 lite. I backed up user data using recovery. However, I'm not able to restore from `.backup` file.

I only have Windows in my PC.

Is there any way i can restore from .backup file using ADB COMMANDS???

Is there anyway I can restore from that backup file, preferably without rooting?

Comment: Related: [How to extract .backup files created by android stock recovery?](//android.stackexchange.com/q/141805)

Comment: I dont have an ubuntu pc. Pls tell me some other way

Comment: @Sarathy You can use a Linux via "Windows Subsystem for Linux" (Win10) or via VirtualBox install an Ubuntu VM. Alternatively all relevant Linux tools are also available on Windows e.g. via Scoop or Chocolatey package managers.

Comment: Sorry for my absence.. somehow i got a copy of ubuntu OS. I am new to linux. So..can Robert or anyone, pls explain/ help with the steps explained at, https://android.stackexchange.com/q/141805.. sorry if am bothering or insisting you guys.. its my fathers mobile. He had passed away.. I am having sentimental things with that backedup .backup files.. thanks in advance