# android ".backup" into data files

Tags: backup

How can i get all my backup data into (data folder) ??

Here is my list of data (i run this command with (**file ***)

```
userdata_20200109_180356.backup:   data
userdata_20200109_180356.backup1:  data
userdata_20200109_180356.backup2:  data
userdata_20200109_180356.backup3:  data
userdata_20200109_180356.backup4:  data
userdata_20200109_180356.backup5:  data
userdata_20200109_180356.backup6:  data
userdata_20200109_180356.backup7:  data
userdata_20200109_180356.backup8:  data
userdata_20200109_180356.backup9:  data
userdata_20200109_180356.backup10: data
userdata_20200109_180356.backup11: data
userdata_20200109_180356.backup12: data
userdata_20200109_180356.backup13: data
```

Can some one help me with that? how can i do this into data files.

Comment: Based on the file names this question is identical: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141805/how-to-extract-backup-files-created-by-android-stock-recovery

Comment: please note if your device uses full disk encryption you need a copy of metadata, otherwise these backup files become useless after factory reset. read back metadata partition with SP Flash Tool

Comment: How can i read back the metadata in SP Flash Tool?

Comment: Thanks i got the preloader.bin now from the phone. but i flashed the phone with wrong rom. i need the right rom now for fix the phone.