# How can I remove a PIN password form a backup?

Tags: data-recovery, huawei, password

I forgot the PIN to my **Huawei TIT-AL00 android** device. So I backed up my user data to a backup file.(user_data__20150913_075028.backup*) I couldn't use ADB to backup as it wasn't enabled in the recovery mode. I had to use the backup user data option from the recovery menu.

Is there a way that I can remove the PIN password from the backup file so that when I restore it and just use the phone without having to type the password? I tried the solution mentioned here : [How to extract .backup files created by android stock recovery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141805/how-to-extract-backup-files-created-by-android-stock-recovery) But this didn't work either.

I am aware that if I had ADB access to the device, I could have removed the password by editing the `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases` or by deleting the `/data/system/gesture.key`. Since I didn't have ADB access to the device I couldn't do this.

Is there a way that I can extract the backup file, delete/edit these files by mannually and then compress so that I can restore it?

Comment: check with hex editor if userdata_20150913_075028.backup is encrypted or plain disk image

Comment: I am not sure whether it's encrypted or not. I used the hexeditor and I can see the hex values. But when I run the "file" command against it, it just tells me "data".

Comment: According to how I understood, if the 0xef53 exists at 0x638 offset of the hexdump it's not encrypted. Correct? If so, mine is not encrypted.

Comment: I was able to bckp2cwm.sh and extract the files and remove the password(as it said). Has the script made required changes to the backup file as well or just extracted it? Can I now just restore it like a normal backup file?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to restore from stock recovery as I don't know how to calculate checksum. you can however restore from custom recovery TWRP

Comment: Actually, I can't access fastboot for some reason. So this is not the way for me. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Okay, I will try. Tbh, I am not that familiar with android work. Anyways, I will try to follow the linked answer. Is there anyway I can reach you if need help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backup/dump kernel image (and full ROM) without root for Mediatek Devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203283/backup-dump-kernel-image-and-full-rom-without-root-for-mediatek-devices)

Comment: try Wwr_MTK and SP Flash Tool. your device most likely is not Qualcomm but Mediatek chipset. instead of EDL mode it has **preloader** mode which is similar